# Prevent print() statement from overwriting text from input() statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

So I'm working on a simple chat server in python.
The server is running fine and on the client I have one thread for receiving incoming data and one for sending messages.

I can send a message from client_1 to the server which passes it to all other clients which will then print the message.

Even though everything technically works fine, there is still one thing that is VERY annoying whenever it happens:

Say client_1 is typing text into the console.
At the same time client_2 sends a message to the server, the server sends it to client_1 and client_1 prints the message.
Now the text client_1 was originally typing into the console is no longer in the line it was supposed to be in.

This is what the consoles looked like before client_2 sent the string "test test": https://ibb.co/hFdeo7

and this is what they looked like after sending: https://ibb.co/mEWAvn

NOTE: If I were to press Enter on client_1 the message "TEST TEST TEST" would still be sent correctly. The problem only lies in the conflict between the text that is being printed and the text in the input() statement.

My code looks like This:

Server.py

```
connections = []

while True:
readable, writeable, exception = select.select(connections, [], [], 0)

for sock in readable:
    if sock == server:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        connections.append(conn)

    else:
        data = str(sock.recv(1024), 'utf8')

        if data:
            for s in connections:
                if s != server_socket and s != sock:
                    s.send(bytes(data, 'utf8'))

        else:
            connections.remove(sock)
```

Client.py

```
def receive():
    while True:
        readable, writeable, exception = select.select([0, client], [], [])

        for sock in readable:
            if sock == client:
                data = str(sock.recv(1024), 'utf8')

                if data:
                    print(data)

def send():
    while True:
        readable, writeable, exception = select.select([0, client], [], [])

        for sock in readable:
            if sock == client:
                pass

            else:
                msg = input()
                client.send(bytes(msg, 'utf8'))

Thread(target=receive).start()
Thread(target=send).start()
```

Is there any way to solve this problem without running the send() and receive() functions in separate scripts, or using a GUI module like Tkinter?

EDIT: I would like to print the incoming message as soon as it is received but then display the input() prompt and typed text again afterwards.

Comment: One thing I don't think you've made clear is what you _want_ to happen in this situation. Should the client wait to display received messages if the user is typing? Should the messages be displayed in a different place? Should the incoming message be printed but then the input prompt and typed text be displayed again afterwards? These are all solutions I've seen.

Comment: For me the best thing would be if it was possible to print the incoming message and display the input prompt and the typed text again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to showing the incoming message and then redisplaying the input prompt and partial input string (as specified in a comment). It uses `readline.get_line_buffer` to read the currently-input string and redisplay it. A warning, though: reading and writing to the same stream from different threads without locking is going to be prone to glitches.

It just requires a small modification to the `receive` function:

```
if data:
    print('\n' + data)
    sys.stdout.write(readline.get_line_buffer())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The `'\n'` in the `print` is so the incoming message doesn't land right on top of whatever's being typed. The `flush` is necessary so that you can write the current input without a newline but without it getting buffered. I might suggest adding a prompt (like `'> '`) to the `input` and the `sys.stdout.write`, just to make it clearer to the user what's happening.

Lastly, running this may mess up your terminal output. You might need to run `reset` afterwards. There's probably a way to clean up that prevents that but I don't know offhand what it is.